# Wordpress use functions.php to run function only on specific page template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a following code to check if current used file is `tmp_home_page.php`, but when I do `echo $template_file;` it is showing `functions.php`

```
    add_action('template_redirect', 'are_we_home_yet', 10);
    function are_we_home_yet(){
            global $template;
            $template_file = basename((__FILE__).$template);
            if ( is_home() && $template_file == 'tmp_home_page.php' ) {

            // do stuff

            }
     }
```

**Any idea how to make sure that my `do stuff` is only run on home page and when given template is in use?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking way too hard into this, there's a wordpress function for that. 
[`is_page_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/)

```
if( is_page_template( 'tmp_home_page.php' ) && is_home() ){
    // Do Stuff
}
```

Also, [`is_front_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/) is usually a better alternative to [`is_home()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/) when trying to determine if a user is viewing the **Front/First Page** of a WordPress site. You can see more on that subject [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/when-to-use-is-home-vs-is-front-page).

Comment: Will this in functions.php file?

Comment: That all depends on the code that you need to do, though based on what you're saying, I presume yes, put it in functions.php