# target specific wordpress page template with functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to target a specific page template, the single.php file with the below function to either deactivate wpautop on the content or the excerpt depending on if the page template is single.php - though I'm not getting it to work:

```
function rem_filter() {
    if (is_page_template('single.php')) 
    {
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); 
    } else {
        remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
    }
}
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'rem_filter');
```

All help would be appreciated. I found this in the forum before asking the question:

[Wordpress use functions.php to run function only on specific page template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203329/wordpress-use-functions-php-to-run-function-only-on-specific-page-template)

thanks!

/k

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be what you are looking for:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );

//decide when you want to apply the auto paragraph

add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_custom_content' );
function my_custom_content( $content ){
    if( is_page_template( 'single.php' ) ){ 
        return $content; //no autop
    }else{
        return wpautop($content);
    }
}

add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'my_custom_excerpt' );
function my_custom_excerpt( $content ){
    if( is_page_template( 'single.php' ) ){ 
        return $content; //no autop
    }else{
        return wpautop($content);
    }
}
```